# Android app getting crash when select image from Recent images from gallery

Tags: android, gallery, recent-file-list

My app work perfectly when select `image from Pictures` or images categories in `Gallery` but app getting crash when `select image from recent images`

This is my intent call

```
galleryLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), perms_gallery)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
            }else {
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(getActivity(), getString(R.string.read_file),
                        READ_REQUEST_CODE, perms_gallery);
            }
        }
    });
```

Crash happen from here `String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];`

```
public String getPathFromUriGallery(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePath, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        return  cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

this my error log

```
Process: io.test.susitkMed.doctor, PID: 9576
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=3;doc=encoded=0ajgvv25pDn5wcNiiiv1YFYu7neaIdrulcWk/kBdEa8TqupNEKLhnLzz flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }} to activity {io.test.susitkMed.doctor/io.test.susitkMed.doctor.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: Please share logic of onActivityResult

Comment: can you explain me  String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; its usage in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution from this github sample https://github.com/maayyaannkk/ImagePicker

This is the solution for above issue

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String   imageEncoded = getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageString);
        image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
    }
}
```

These method use for get image url

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    OutputStream out;
    File file = new File(getFilename(context));

    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            InputStream iStream = context != null ? context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri) : context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
            byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(inputData);
            out.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}

private String getFilename(Context context) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(""), "patient_data");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    String mImageName = "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
    return mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + mImageName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods instead..

```
public String getImagePathFromUri(Uri contentUri) {
            String res = null;
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                res = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            cursor.close();
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: Using this code your handling only crash but still image path return null, So this is not a solution for my problem :(

Comment: are you getting contentUri null??

Comment: by the way do you have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ?????

Comment: yes , Note: my code work perfectly when select image from pictures or images but not working when select from recent image section

Comment: try to run your app in some other device,, I think your gallery app is not returning anything..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Document provider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) instead.

For eg:

```
Intent it = new Intent();
it.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
it.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(it, 1000);

----------------------

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromUri(data.getData());
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**When I select the image from recent then the image is broken in android | Multiple images from recent**

I have mentioned below my answer link please go there and find your solutions

[You can find the full post from this link || Click link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68527528/6897956)

Also, you can find here

[Sample preview](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/glide-2-min.gif)

> **Call multiple images select**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        *gallery*.launch(i);
```

> gallery basically startActivityForResult(i,123) and OnActivityResult method is deprecated, the *gallery* is alternative which is defined below

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> gallery = choosePhotoFromGallery();
```

and **choosePhotoFromGallery()** is method which is define below

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    return registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                try {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        if (null != result.getData()) {
                            if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {
                                ClipData mClipData = result.getData().getClipData();
                                for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                    ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                                    String imageFilePathColumn = getPathFromURI(this, uri);
                                    productImagesList.add(imageFilePathColumn);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (result.getData().getData() != null) {
                                    Uri mImageUri = result.getData().getData();
                                    String imageFilePathColumn = getPathFromURI(this, mImageUri);
                                    productImagesList.add(imageFilePathColumn);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            showToast(this, "You haven't picked Image");
                            productImagesList.clear();
                        }
                    } else {
                        productImagesList.clear();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showToast(this, "Something went wrong");
                    productImagesList.clear();
                }
            });
}
```

and ***getPathFromURI()*** is method which define below

```
 public String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    OutputStream out;
    File file = getPath();

    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            InputStream iStream = context != null ? context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri) : context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
            byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(inputData);
            out.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

and the ***getPath()*** is

```
private File getPath() {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(folder.getPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: Please don't add same answer on multiple old  post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with **ACTION_GET_CONTENT**.

This is because it allows user to pick the image from ***Recent***.

In order to solve the problem, I highly recommend using **ACTION_PICK**.

**[SOLVED]**:

```
galleryLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getActivity(), perms_gallery)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);              
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
            }else {
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(getActivity(), getString(R.string.read_file),
                        READ_REQUEST_CODE, perms_gallery);
            }
        }
    });
```