# When i select image from recent then image is broken in android | Multiple images from recent

Tags: java, android, gallery, android-glide, recent-file-list

> ***This error occurs mostly times when select images from recent folder***

```
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Call multiple images select**

[**Sample Preview**](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/glide-2-min.gif)

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        *gallery*.launch(i);
```

> gallery basically startActivityForResult(i,123) and OnActivityResult method is deprecated, the *gallery* is alternative which is defined below

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> gallery = choosePhotoFromGallery();
```

and **choosePhotoFromGallery()** is method which is define below

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    return registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                try {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        if (null != result.getData()) {
                            if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {
                                ClipData mClipData = result.getData().getClipData();
                                for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                    ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                                    String imageFilePathColumn = getPathFromURI(this, uri);
                                    productImagesList.add(imageFilePathColumn);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (result.getData().getData() != null) {
                                    Uri mImageUri = result.getData().getData();
                                    String imageFilePathColumn = getPathFromURI(this, mImageUri);
                                    productImagesList.add(imageFilePathColumn);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            showToast(this, "You haven't picked Image");
                            productImagesList.clear();
                        }
                    } else {
                        productImagesList.clear();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showToast(this, "Something went wrong");
                    productImagesList.clear();
                }
            });
}
```

and ***getPathFromURI()*** is method which define below

```
 public String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    OutputStream out;
    File file = getPath();

    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            InputStream iStream = context != null ? context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri) : context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
            byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(inputData);
            out.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

and the ***getPath()*** is

```
private File getPath() {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(folder.getPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
}
```

## **THANK YOU IN ADVANCE** **HAPPY CODING**